# Is there a standard way to indicate what the associative keys of a parameter that is passed in should be in phpDocumentor

Tags: php, phpdoc

For example

```
 * @param array $an_Array An array of stuff that is needed.
                an_associate_key Description about this key.
                another_key Another Description.
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with phpDocumentor, but I don't think assumptions should be made about this. If you do make assumptions about this (for a config. array in example) you should check and provide defaults for the missing key/value pairs.

Comment: Very interesting question! I've been using a personnal syntax for this (trying to be consistent across the documentation), but if something "official" exists and is parsed by phpdocumentor, I'm interested to know.

Comment: @Alexander Or throw an error. But that is irrelevant as far as documentation is concerned. Default or not, it is handy to know what can be passed in.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get it parsed by phpDocumentor. The only way (you mentioend it yourself) is to describe it in the parameters' description.

As a side note: phPDocumentor seems to be not really maintained anymore. You may have a look at [DocBlox](http://www.docblox-project.org/) and write a feature request in its [issue tracker](https://github.com/mvriel/docblox/issues)

Comment: For anyone reading this in the future" DocBlox is now phpDocumentor v2